# Multi-geometry validation in WFS service using GML

Tags: geometry, gml, validation

I'm doing the test to introduce multiple geometry in a WFS service using GML.

For now the simple geometry is functional, but I still have some bugs with multiple geometry.
I think it may come from my GML and XSD which are not valid in multiple geometry.

(validation with this site : http://cite.opengeospatial.org/test_engine/gml/2.1.2 )

The two errors reported :

http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=329637Sanstitre1.png

Here is the code of my two test files.
The GML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gml2:FeatureCollection xmlns:gml2="http://www.safe.com/gml2"  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.safe.com/gml2 Test_creche_multi_geometry.xsd">
<gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:Box srsName="EPSG:31370">
        <gml:coordinates>184929.649440012,128365.014231805 184946.357440016,128378.548198801</gml:coordinates>
    </gml:Box>
</gml:boundedBy>
<gml:featureMember>
    <gml2:Test_creche_multi_geometry>
                <gml2:CODEPICC>xxxxx</gml2:CODEPICC>
                <gml2:CLE>xxxxx</gml2:CLE>
                <gml2:RUE>xxxxx</gml2:RUE>
                <gml2:NUMERO>xxxxx</gml2:NUMERO>
                <gml2:CODEPOSTAL>xxxxx</gml2:CODEPOSTAL>
                <gml2:LOCALITE>xxxxx</gml2:LOCALITE>
                <gml2:COMMUNE>xxxxx</gml2:COMMUNE>
                <gml2:ITINERAIRE>xxxxx</gml2:ITINERAIRE>
                <gml2:FONCTION>xxxxx</gml2:FONCTION>
        <MultiGeometry>
            <geometryMember>
                <gml:polygonProperty>
                    <gml:Polygon srsName="EPSG:31370">
                        <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                            <gml:LinearRing>
                                <gml:coordinates>
                    184945.971440009,128372.235198804,98.9550000000017 184945.033210008,128365.014231805,96.0626999999949 184929.649440012,128367.213198801,98.8849999999948 184931.385440006,128378.548198801,95.9250000000029 184943.227440013,128376.6961988,98.8410000000003 184946.357440016,128376.194198803,98.8380000000034 184945.971440009,128372.235198804,98.9550000000017
                                </gml:coordinates>
                            </gml:LinearRing>
                        </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                    </gml:Polygon>
                </gml:polygonProperty>
            </geometryMember>
            <geometryMember>
                <gml:pointProperty>
                    <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:31370">
                            <gml:coordinates>184938.100676204,128371.723142331</gml:coordinates>
                    </gml:Point>
                </gml:pointProperty>
            </geometryMember>
        </MultiGeometry>    
    </gml2:Test_creche_multi_geometry>
</gml:featureMember>
</gml2:FeatureCollection>
```

The XSD :

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:gml2="http://www.safe.com/gml2"     targetNamespace="http://www.safe.com/gml2" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml"     schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/2.1.2/feature.xsd"/>
<element name="FeatureCollection" type="gml2:FeatureCollectionType"     substitutionGroup="gml:_FeatureCollection"/>
<element name="Test_creche_multi_geometry" type="gml2:Test_creche_multi_geometryType" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature"/>
<complexType name="FeatureCollectionType">
<complexContent>
<extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureCollectionType"></extension>
</complexContent>
</complexType>
<complexType name="MultiGeometryPropertyType">
<complexContent>
<extension base="gml:GeometryAssociationType"></extension>
</complexContent>
</complexType>
<complexType name="Test_creche_multi_geometryType">
<complexContent>
<extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
<sequence>
<element name="CODEPICC" type="integer"/>
<element name="CLE">
<simpleType>
<restriction base="string">
<maxLength value="254"/>
</restriction>
</simpleType>
</element>
<element name="RUE">
<simpleType>
<restriction base="string">
<maxLength value="254"/>
</restriction>
</simpleType>
</element>
<element name="NUMERO">
<simpleType>
<restriction base="string">
<maxLength value="254"/>
</restriction>
</simpleType>
</element>
<element name="CODEPOSTAL">
<simpleType>
<restriction base="string">
<maxLength value="254"/>
</restriction>
</simpleType>
</element>
<element name="LOCALITE">
<simpleType>
<restriction base="string">
<maxLength value="254"/>
</restriction>
</simpleType>
</element>
<element name="COMMUNE">
<simpleType>
<restriction base="string">
<maxLength value="254"/>
</restriction>
</simpleType>
</element>
<element name="ITINERAIRE">
<simpleType>
<restriction base="string">
<maxLength value="254"/>
</restriction>
</simpleType>
</element>
<element name="FONCTION">
<simpleType>
<restriction base="string">
<maxLength value="254"/>
</restriction>
</simpleType>
</element>
<choice>
<element ref="gml:MultiGeometry"/>
<element ref="gml:polygonProperty"/>
<element ref="gml:pointProperty"/>
</choice>
</sequence>
</extension>
</complexContent>
</complexType>
</schema>
```

---

I forgot to put "gml:" before multigeometry and multimember. My mistakes have decreased.

The .xsd is valid but not yet the gml. I also changed multimember into multimembers.

For the validation error gml, the error is still the same as before.

I still can not generate the sd. ArcGIS Server in order to allow the generation of a wfs service.

http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/670546gijhfhbc.png